Infinite Loading when executing a function through "On Select"
I have an application in Power Apps that is experiencing an issue. When a user selects a button that should execute a formula,90% of the tries the formula runs accordingly, but sometimes it starts running and never complete.
In order to try to understand where is the problem on the execution i've added a collect on each iteraction of the patch functions, and added a text label control to show the CountRows value of these collections, by doing this it was clear that this freeze happens before any "collect", as the text labels just show "0".
I've tried to disconnect the device from the internet as well, trying to force an error, it didn't work, powerapps didn't display any errors, the loading just continues to run indefinitely.
I have no idea what might be causing this problem.
Here is the formula I am using, there is something wrong with this formula ou is it something related to power apps?:
UpdateContext({varenviofinal: true});
UpdateContext({patchSuccess: true});
Set(
    qtdDados,
    CountRows(colCriterios)
);
Set(
    qtdFotos,
    CountRows(colFotos)
);
Clear(qtdDados2);
Clear(qtdFotos2);
Clear(DatabaseErrors);
Clear(PhotoErrors);

Concurrent((
    ForAll(
        colCriterios,
        Patch(
            '5S Database',
            Defaults('5S Database'),
            {
                Date: DataCardValue2.SelectedDate,
                Auditor: auditor_combobox.Selected.Value,
                Location: varLocal,
                Sense: SENSO,
                'Individual Comment': comentario,
                'Sense ID': ID,
                Category: SENSO2,
                Zone: DataCardValue4.Selected.Value,
                Rating: classificacao
            }
        );
        If(
            !IsEmpty(Errors('5S Database')),
            Collect(
                DatabaseErrors,
                Errors('5S Database')
            )
        );
        Collect(
            qtdDados2,
            {processed: true}
        );
    )
),(
    ForAll(
        'Current Audit Photos_3'.AllItems,
        If(
            IsEmpty(PhotoErrors),
            Patch(
                '5S Photos',
                Defaults('5S Photos'),
                {
                    Date: ThisRecord.Date,
                    Zone: Zone,
                    Auditor: auditor,
                    Sense: Sense,
                    Category: Category,
                    'Sense ID': 'Sense ID',
                    Photo: ThisRecord.Image4.Image
                }
            );
            If(
                !IsEmpty(Errors('5S Photos')),
                Collect(
                    PhotoErrors,
                    Errors('5S Photos')
                )
            );
            Collect(
                qtdFotos2,
                {processed: true}
            );
        )
    )
));
If(
    IsEmpty(PhotoErrors),
    Notify(
        "Photos successfully sent",
        NotificationType.Success
    ),
    Notify(
        "Something went wrong",
        NotificationType.Error
    );
    UpdateContext({patchSuccess: false}) // Add this line to update the patch success variable if there is an error
);
If(
    IsEmpty(DatabaseErrors),
    Notify(
        "Information successfully sent, starting photo upload",
        NotificationType.Success
    ),
    Notify(
        "Something went wrong",
        NotificationType.Error
    );
    UpdateContext({patchSuccess: false}) // Add this line to update the patch success variable if there is an error
);
UpdateContext({varenviofinal: false});
// Modify this line to check the patch success variable before navigating
If(
    !patchSuccess,
    Navigate(
        'Error Tables',
        ScreenTransition.Fade
    ),
    Navigate(
        'Home Screen',
        ScreenTransition.Fade
    );
    UpdateContext({varPopUp: false})
)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I've tried to disconnect the internet to force an error but it did not work. I'm also using a countRows for the collections related to data and Photos so the user can see the progress of the patch, and when this error occurs the countrows is stuck on 0.
